# Why can't I programatically set the value on my hidden field on a repeater?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've had this strange problem come up. I have a `RowDataBound` event handler for a repeater control.

I have the code:

```
HiddenField hfIpAddressRangeId = (HiddenField)e.Row.FindControl("hfIpAddressRangeId");
hfIpAddressRangeId.Value = .IpAddressRangeId.ToString();
```

But when I look at the html the value of that control is not set. However when I set the value using inline C# such as

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("IpAddressRangeId ") %>' ID="hfIpAddressRangeId" ViewStateMode="Enabled" />
```

The value is being set. I'm not really sure why this won't work when I bind each datarow?

Comment: Does this `IpAddressRangeId.ToString()` actually hold any value in the DataBound event ?

Comment: have you tried setting the hidden field to a static value in the rowdatabound handler, rather than ipaddressrangeid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like `IpAddressRangeId` is a part of your datasource, hence the use of `Eval` in the second example. Have you tried this?:

```
HiddenField hfIpAddressRangeId = (HiddenField)e.Row.FindControl("hfIpAddressRangeId"); 
hfIpAddressRangeId.Value = DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "IpAddressRangeId").ToString();
```